# Can someone interpret this error message?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

When i run this code:

```
import os

openfile = open('/home/pi/cmds.txt', 'r+')
command = openfile.read()

if command != "":
    os.system(command)
    openfile.write("")
```

I get this error message:

> sh: l: The: not found

anyone know whats going on?

(the eagle eyed of you might have worked out i'm running this on a raspberry pi)

Comment: What's the content of the file you're trying to execute? The problem is probably in there.

Answer (score 0):

The code is opening a file and trying to execute whatever is contained in the file as a shell command.

What it happens is that the **content** is not a valid command, and that's why there is an error.

Comment: I will now put this to the test!

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the `command` variable before you call `os.system()`. It's probably not what you think it is.

Here is how I can achieve a fairly similar effect with my `/bin/sh`:

```
sh-3.2$ "l: The"
sh: l: The: command not found
```